# How to format the name of an R package in thesis?

Tags: thesis, software, formatting

In a thesis, when referring to an R package (a statistical software), how should I write it?

Should it be italicized/treated like a title?

Or just like any other word. The package name is not a "normal word" so it seems out of place to just write it like

"...using the R package XYZ."

Comment: Why not using the convention employed in the [R documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/manuals.html) (package names are typeset with a bold font)?

Comment: Also remember to include what version of R and package you used.

Comment: You may be overthinking this. I think the text version is okay. You may or may not emphasise the package name but the reader will get that it is a R package from the sentence, so the rest is a question how you like it better yourself.

Comment: As far as I've seen there isn't an agreed-upon convention here, but people often distinguish package names with a different font than the regular text.  A monospace typeface (e.g. `\texttt{ggplot2}` in LaTeX) or bold font is common choice.

Answer (score 2):

In LaTeX, you can do this by adding the following to your preamble. Something like this:

```
\newcommand{\pkg}[1]{{\normalfont\fontseries{b}\selectfont #1}}
\let\proglang=\textsf \let\code=\texttt

\begin{document}

Then you can refer to R as \proglang{R}, to a package
\pkg{packagename}, and to a function as \code{functionname}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: The OP didn't mention they were working in LATEX.

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- That is correct! I just assumed OP is writing a thesis and using R; therefore, in the science field, where most of the thesis is written in Latex!

Comment: Biologists still write papers by emailing each other word documents. The really clever ones might be on Google docs now.

Comment: @AhmadTalafha I don't think you can say most of the sciences use LaTeX - most of math, maybe.

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- While it is true, check out this post https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/940/what-professions-use-tex-latex-besides-cs

Comment: @Libor Google Docs is great! For Latex, check out Overleaf, it is a collaborative cloud-based LaTeX editor used for writing, editing and publishing scientific documents.

Comment: @AhmadTalafha Sure, but there's a lot more to science than math, physics, and linguistics ;)

Answer (score 1):

In R, use the `citation` function and inside the function use the argument package and then put the name of the package you wish to cite in quotations. Below is an example of the code.

```
citation(package = "NAME OF PACKAGE HERE")
```

You can copy the output to place in your document in the references.

For in-text citations, you can follow APA recommendations for citing software. Below is an example

- The Foo package was used in the analysis (Version number; Author last name, year).

Comment: The question isn't about how to cite the package, it's about how to format the name of the package when referring to it in text. e.g.: "We use the foo package to parse the data and..."